# How do I change CCScrollLayer content size? (cocos2d extension class)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, cocos2d-iphone, ccscrolllayer

I am currently using the CCScrollLayer (in the cocos2d extension classes) class to implement a menu system. It's working great but I would like to have other buttons on the screen and the scrollable area is the entire screen by default.

I tried messing with content size but no dice. After doing some reading, I found that the content size is set to the screen size per CCLayers behavior. A user suggested wrapping it in a CCNode and scaling, but this did not help.

Any suggestions or sample code? I'd have to think this should be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help, unfortunately it seems you cannot change the size of a CCLayer (or the contentSize has no effect on touch events) without basically rewriting a lot of code.

However, I found a workaround that seems to be working.  In the ccTouch events began and moved, I check my desired bounds after converting my UITouch to cocos2D space.  If they are not in the my bounds I return, and in the case of move I manually call TouchEnded.  TouchEnded also checks the initial touched point, and if it is was out of bounds it ignores it.

Things seems to be working as desired.  I will post more information if I find it.  Thanks again everyone.

Answer (score 0):

`CAScrollLayer` is surprisingly simple, which may be confusing.

Just add the content layer to it:

```
[_scrollLayer addSublayer:_contentLayer];
```

To set the rect you want to be visible on the screen set bounds or frame of the scroll layer:

```
[_scrollLayer setBounds:visibleBounds];
```

Set the content's size respectively. The content's size can be bigger or smaller, it does not matter.

```
[_contentLayer setBounds:currentContextBounds];
```

If the content is bigger and you want to scroll to a certain point use `scrollToPoint:` or `scrollToRect:` methods of the scroll layer.

You need to implement your own scrolling indicators, bars, etc. if desired.

Comment: This question is specifically for CCScrollLayer (the cocos2d extension class) I would use one of the UIKit classes if it didn't have severe performance hits in cocos2d.  Sorry question was maybe a bit confusing.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have not paid attention to the spelling. Unfortunately, I can't help you with cocos2d.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am using table view and not the scroll view, both share the same parent [scroll view doh].
Have you turned on clipToBounds after setting content size?

I would recommend using this constructor:

```
/**
 * Init this object with a given size to clip its content.
 *
 * @param size view size
 * @return initialized scroll view object
 */
- (id)initWithViewSize:(CGSize)size;
```

Comment: Hmm I cant find clipToBounds property.  CCScrollViews parent is CCLayer though which is a child of CCNode.

Comment: Maybe Im not using the same CCScrollView cause it doesnt have that constructor.  I am using one from the 3rd party extensions. https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/tree/release-0.2  I think I used CCTableView in my old project but really had to hack a lot of stuff together, this one seems great (paging support, very smooth) but I cant set the content size which is maddening.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it. I am using this one: https://github.com/saim80/Cocos2D-Extensions and it works pretty fine. I know that on cocos2d forums some people changed the names to start with CC, that's why I thought you were using this one. It might be easy to implement clipping in the one you are using. I've created some scroll layers on my own, it's just a matter of adding onEnter, onExit and two [afair] more methods [copy & paste should be enough]

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like they have made a bunch of updates since I implemented in my game last year.  Will give it a shot and see if it works well enough.  Will post again later.